# How to numpy searchsorted bisect a range of 2 values on 1 column and get min value in 2nd column

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a 2 column numpy array of integers, say:

```
tarray = array([[ 368,  322],
       [ 433,  420],
       [ 451,  412],
       [ 480,  440],
       [ 517,  475],
       [ 541,  503],
       [ 578,  537],
       [ 607,  567],
       [ 637,  599],
       [ 666,  628],
       [ 696,  660],
       [ 726,  687],
       [ 756,  717],
       [ 785,  747],
       [ 815,  779],
       [ 845,  807],
       [ 874,  837],
       [ 905,  867],
       [ 934,  898],
       [ 969,  928],
       [ 994,  957],
       [1027,  987],
       [1057, 1017],
       [1086, 1047],
       [1117, 1079],
       [1148, 1109],
       [1177, 1137],
       [1213, 1167],
       [1237, 1197],
       [1273, 1227],
       [1299, 1261],
       [1333, 1287],
       [1357, 1317],
       [1393, 1347],
       [1416, 1377]])
```

I am using np.searchsorted to bisect lower and upper ranges of values into column 0 i.e can both times e.g 241,361 bisect into the array.

```
ranges = [array([241, 290, 350, 420, 540, 660, 780, 900]),
 array([ 361,  410,  470,  540,  660,  780,  900, 1020])]
```

e.g: np.searchsorted(tarray[:,0], ranges)

This then results in:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  5,  9, 13, 17],
       [ 0,  1,  3,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21]])
```

where each position in the two resulting arrays is the range of values. What I then want to do is get the position of minimum value in column 1 of the resulting slice. e.g here is what I mean simply in Python via iteration (if result of searchsorted is 2 column array 'f'):

```
f = array([[ 0,  0,  0,  1,  5,  9, 13, 17],
       [ 0,  1,  3,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21]])

for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(*f)):
    if y - x:
        print ranges[1][i], tarray[x:y]
```

the result is:

```
410 [[368 322]]
470 [[368 322]
 [433 420]
 [451 412]]
540 [[433 420]
 [451 412]
 [480 440]
 [517 475]]
660 [[541 503]
 [578 537]
 [607 567]
 [637 599]]
780 [[666 628]
 [696 660]
 [726 687]
 [756 717]]
900 [[785 747]
 [815 779]
 [845 807]
 [874 837]]
1020 [[905 867]
 [934 898]
 [969 928]
 [994 957]]
```

Now to explain what I want: within the sliced ranges I want the row that has the minimum value in column 1.

```
e.g 540 [[433 420]
 [451 412]
 [480 440]
 [517 475]]
```

I want the final result to be 412 (as in [451 412])

e.g

```
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(*f)):
    if y - x:
        print ranges[1][i], tarray[:,1:2][x:y].min()

410 322
470 322
540 412
660 503
780 628
900 747
1020 867
```

Basically I want to vectorise this so I can get back one array and not need to iterate as it is non performant for my needs. I want the minimum value in column 1 for a bisected range of values on column 0.

I hope I am being clear!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to achieve your intended goals, using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
# to vectorize the concatenation of the slice ranges, we construct all indices implied in the slicing
counts = f[1] - f[0]
idx = np.ones(counts.sum(), dtype=np.int)
idx[np.cumsum(counts)[:-1]] -= counts[:-1]
tidx = np.cumsum(idx) - 1 + np.repeat(f[0], counts)

# combined with a unique label tagging the output of each slice range, this allows us to use grouping to find the minimum in each group
label = np.repeat(np.arange(len(f.T)), counts)
subtarray = tarray[tidx]
ridx, sidx = npi.group_by(label).argmin(subtarray[:, 0])

print(ranges[1][ridx])
print(subtarray[sidx, 1])
```

Comment: Good job! I was thinking along the same lines and thought pandas groupby could be used.

Comment: yeah, it was an interesting question; constructing the indices from a sequence of slices was trickier than I intuited; I still feel like I might be missing something much simpler.

Comment: Hmm you could do something like `id_arr = np.ones(counts.sum(),dtype=int); 
id_arr[np.append(0,counts[:-1].cumsum())] = np.append(0,f[0,1:] - f[1,:-1]+1)` and then `tidx` would be `id_arr.cumsum()-1`. If you have filtered out the invalid ones, e.g. the first entry from `f`, you would avoid that `-1` to get `tidx`. I guess the only benefit would be avoiding `np.repeat`, not sure if it's worth it though. Also, for performance, it would make sense to split it into two steps to avoid that appending and indexing into the first and rest of entries separately.